# Do any unique items spawn in (upgraded) houses?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

You can spend a lot of money upgrading your house(s) in Skyrim, which will eventually include things like food, potions and ingredients spawning in the house (one-off or respawning, I'm still not sure, but that's a different question!).

Are there any unique items that are *only* obtainable from upgrading a house (either fully or partially)? I think I read something about a Stone of Berenziah spawning in an upgraded house but I can't find a source for that. Perhaps some weapon or armour gets added to a display stand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the 25 Stones of Berenziah is in Proudspire Manor, but this does not require any upgrades.

There are no unique items for upgrading any house, however.

Comment: There are some non-unique but rare items found in upgraded houses. The ingredients sachel in the alchemy table in the house in Whiterun contains a human heart.

Answer (score 1):

You are right you can get Stone of Berenziah from upgrading one of the houses (proudspire manor). No unique weapons/items are found as far as I can tell from experience.

source - my experiance and http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Stones_of_Barenziah

Comment: do you have to upgrade the house or just _buy_ it? The wiki doesn't mention upgrades.

Comment: The wiki says - "in the master bedroom", implies you need the bedroom upgrades. I cannot tell you specifically as I bought all the upgrade at the same time, I had loads of money.

Comment: Not sure that implies needing the upgrades - the master bedroom is still the master bedroom, even if it's a cobwebby mess :)

Comment: easily verified by buying the house and checking out the master bedroom. the house is not all that big or all that far away.

Comment: true! but I'm at work at the moment (and I haven't been to Solitude yet, either!) so it's hard to check :D +1 for the Stone info anyway.

Comment: @Alex as my answer indicates, you do not need to buy any upgrades for it to be present.